# How can I format an entire source tree in Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede)?

Tags: eclipse

The obvious thing to do would be to:

1. Right-click on the folder that you wish to format.
2. Source > Format

Expected results:
- All java code in the directory and subdirectories are formatted (using the project specific formatting settings)

Actual results:
- None of the java is formatted.

While we're at it, how can we do a batch clean up operation in Eclipse?
From editor, I Right-click > Source > Clean Up, but I can only do one file at a time.

Comment: Funny, this works for "Organize Imports"

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same issue. I had to switch to packaged Explorer to use the formatter.  Under Navigator it does not work. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg22969.html), this (format all Java source files within a folder) should work since eclipse3.0.

Do you see some kind of error message in the "errors view" ?

Comment: I didn't get any error messages. I noticed that several XML files were touched.

Maybe I did something wrong. I'll try again. Tried again:

The problem is definitely that only XML files are formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly as you suggested you would like to do, and it did exactly what you suggested was expected.  I selected Source | Format for a directory in my src tree and it reformatted all the units within.

EDIT: ...with 3.4.1 Ganymede.

Answer (score 0):

If your code isn't checked out from source control or isn't writable, doing a group operation like this won't check them out or make them writable.

Comment: The files are all writable / checked out (using the Eclipse subversion integration [plus we have Tortoise for use in Explorer]).

Comment: In that case, I don't know why you didn't get the same results as @JMD, or as I did when I tried "Organize Imports" on a whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.5.1

- I am using the package explorer
- The project is in a SVN repository that is checked out
- In the progress dialog I can see that only the XML files are modified
- When I press Ctrl+Shift+F into a file, it gets reformatted (therefore is writable) but when after a reverse I do a right-click Source > Format on its folder nothing happens

I know it's been 2 years but I was wondering if @LES2 has found a workaround to correct this

EDIT : 
Okay, despite I was really in the package explorer as written before, my java code was interpreted only as text files. I re-ran the full repository check-out of my project and a package-tree (squares for packages instead of folders) appeared giving me the ability to mass-format even Java files.